# WooCommerce Add item to Order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I'm trying to add an item to an existent order but it's not working properly... Everytime I execute the code below it ads and empty item, any help?

```
woocommerce_add_order_item($Novo_PostId, $item);
```

$item is the var witch receives the item itself from another order I have, I've put a print_r($item) and it appears to be ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you create your item with `woocommerce_add_order_item` you have to set the meta data with `woocommerce_add_order_item_meta()`, see: http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_add_order_item_meta.html

Something like:

```
            $item_id = woocommerce_add_order_item( $order_id, array(
                    'order_item_name'       => '',
                    'order_item_type'       => 'line_item'
            ) );

            if ( $item_id ) {

                    $foreach($metavalues as $key=>$value)
                    {
                    woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id,$key,$value);
                    }
             }
```

Answer (score 9):

Since WC 2.2, adding an item to a new order is simpler:

```
 $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

 wc_get_order($order_id)->add_product($product, $quantity);
```