# WooCommerce Add item to Order with item order meta

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, orders

I would like to delete an existing WooComerce item and add x new WooComerce items from it. It depends on how high the $ item-> quantity is.

My code looks like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_change_status_function', 10, 1 );

function my_change_status_function( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        if ( $item->get_quantity() > 1 ) {
            wc_delete_order_item( $item_id );
            for ( $i = 1; $i <= $item->get_quantity(); $i++ ) {
                $new_item_ids = woocommerce_add_order_item(
                    $order_id,
                    array(
                        'order_item_name' => $item->get_name() . '_' . $i,
                        'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
                    )
                );

                if ( $new_item_ids ) {

                    foreach ( $metavalues as $key => $value ) {
                        wc_add_order_item_meta( $new_item_ids, $key, $value );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The point where I'm a little bit desperate is here:

```
if ( $new_item_ids ) {

    foreach ( $metavalues as $key => $value ) { <-- I dont know where i get the $metavalues
    wc_add_order_item_meta( $new_item_ids, $key, $value );
    }
}
```

I've already tried this post from Stackoverflow:

[WooCommerce Add item to Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241467/woocommerce-add-item-to-order)

Could someone help me?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since WooCommerce 3 your code is outdated and can be simplified using some `WC_Abstract_Order` methods. Also you should better use `woocommerce_checkout_order_created` hook instead, that is triggered after order is created:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'separate_order_items_by_quantity' );
function separate_order_items_by_quantity( $order ) {
    $items_processed = false; // Initializing

    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $quantity = $item->get_quantity(); // Get quantity
        $product  = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product Object

        // When item has quatity more than 1, separete items by quantity
        if ( $item->get_quantity() > 1 ) {
            $order->remove_item( $item_id ); // Remove item
            $items_processed = true; // Flag it

            // Loop through quantity
            for ( $i = 1; $i <= $quantity; $i++ ) {
                // Add the same productb (separated) n times the quantity
                $new_item_id = $order->add_product( $product, 1, array(
                    '_custom_index' => $i, // (required) to have separated products
                    'name'          => $product->get_name() . ' ' . $i, // (optional) change product name appending the index
                    'Some meta key' => 'some meta value', // (optional) Here you can set a custom meta key and its value (custom order item meta data) … To hide it from customer the metakey should start with an underscore.
                ) );
            }
        }
    }

    if( $items_processed ) {
        $order->apply_changes(); // Merge changes with data and clear
        $order->save(); // Save data
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Also, can you tell me if my logic what im trying is usefull? When my code is a little bit to overwhelming please tell me. Im always here to learn more.